# Запятая и тире при деепричастном обороте

Tags: пунктуация

Правильная ли пунктуация в предложении? Правильно ли поставлено тире и запятая, учитывая деепричастный оборот?

Таким образом, не проникая специально на четыре базы врага – северную, восточную, западную, южную, - все эти цели были уничтожены разом за счет применения ядерного оружия.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Употребление деепричастного оборота в приведенном предложении не соответствует правилам Розенталя http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm

Из правил Розенталя: Если  **производитель действия**, обозначенного глаголом-сказуемым, и производитель действия, обозначенного деепричастием, не совпадают, **употребление деепричастного оборота стилистически ошибочно.**

В ряде случаев возможно употребление деепричастного оборота, не выражающего действия подлежащего:

2)  **в безличном предложении при инфинитиве, например:** **Приходилось работать** в трудных условиях, не имея в течение многих недель ни одного свободного дня для отдыха.

2) Предложение после редактирования:

*Таким образом, не проникая специально на четыре базы врага — **северную, восточную, западную, южную**, — **оказалось возможным** разом **уничтожить** все эти цели за счет применения ядерного оружия.*

3) Пояснение (краткое)

Вставная конструкция обособлена двумя тире, а запятая ставится только перед вторым тире, закрывая деепричастный оборот.

Перед первым тире запятой нет,  так как вставка относится к деепричастному обороту.

Comment: *Вставная конструкция обособлена двумя тире, а запятая ставится после второго тире...* Наверное, не после второго, а перед ним?

Comment: Точно, перед ним. Спасибо, Артем.

Answer (score 1):

> Таким образом, не проникая специально на четыре базы врага – северную,
>   восточную, западную, южную, – все эти цели были уничтожены разом за
>   счет применения ядерного оружия.

Запятая тут - святое дело: она не может не закрыть оборот.

А тире я просто люблю, но его присутствию в Вашем примере есть куча обоснований (это ж вставная конструкция, бесспорно ж?), в частности премиленькая "симметрия знаков":

[В зависимости от синтаксической структуры предложения и вставной конструкции на месте «разрыва» основного предложения, помимо тире, могут быть еще запятые. Здесь возможны следующие случаи:](http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=319)

> 1) с обеих сторон ставится только тире, если в месте вставки
>   дополнительных сведений не должно быть никакого знака препинания:
>   Аннушка молча покинула свою засаду, тихо обошла кругом — её детские
>   ножки едва шумели по густой траве — и вышла из чащи подле самого
>   старика (Т.); И — бывают же чудеса — подковылял Воропаев (Павл.);
>   Кругом — не обнять глазом — снежная пелена (Ш.);
>
> 2) перед первым тире ставится запятая, если этого требует структура
>   первой части основного предложения: Он посмотрел на пепелище, которое
>   окружало его, — какой ужас! — и руки бессильно опустились у него —
>   запятая закрывает придаточную часть сложноподчиненного предложения;
>
> 3) перед вторым тире ставится запятая, если этого требует структура
>   второй части основного предложения или вставной конструкции:
>
> Прихвастнуть любил — этот грех за ним водился, — может, и тут что
>   приплёл для красного словца (Фурм.) — вторая часть начинается вводным
>   словом, которое требует выделения запятыми;
>
> …Встал Максим-то против дедушки — а дед ему по плечи, — встал и
>   говорит… (М. Г.) — играет роль повторение слова встал [ср. §40, п. 2];
>
> Он встал и, прихрамывая — он был на протезе, — подошёл к окну (Кав.) —
>   вставному предложению предшествует деепричастие, и запятая ставится,
>   после всей этой конструкции;
>
> Когда он начинает сомневаться в себе — а это с ним изредка происходит,
>   — он пытается стать рационалистом — вставное предложение примыкает к
>   предшествующей придаточной части сложноподчиненного предложения, и
>   запятая ставится после всей конструкции;
>
> Смеялся он мало — настолько у него хватало чувства такта, — но всё же
>   насмешливая улыбка нет-нет да и появлялась на его губах — вторая часть
>   начинается с союза, перед которым должна быть запятая;
>
> 4) как перед первым, так и перед вторым тире ставится запятая по
>   условиям текста:
>
> Проводя почти всё своё время неразлучно с матерью, потому что я и
>   писал и читал в её отдельной горнице, где обыкновенно и спал, — там
>   стояла моя кроватка и там был мой дом, — я менее играл с сестрицей,
>   реже виделся с ней (Акс.) — запятая перед первым тире закрывает
>   предшествующую придаточную часть, запятая перед вторым тире закрывает
>   деепричастную конструкцию;
>
> Я забрался в угол, в кожаное кресло, такое большое, что в нём можно
>   было лежать, — дедушка всегда хвастался, называя его креслом князя
>   Грузинского, — забрался и смотрел, как скучно веселятся большие (М.
>   Г.) — запятая перед первым тире закрывает предшествующую придаточную
>   часть, а запятая перед вторым тире закрывает деепричастный оборот в
>   самой вставной конструкции;
>
> Прежде чем мы расстанемся, — а некоторые из нас вернутся сюда, быть
>   может, не скоро, — прежде чем мы расстанемся, я хотел бы ещё раз
>   вернуться к только что сказанным словам о нашей дружбе — играет роль
>   повторение слов прежде чем мы расстанемся.
>
> Следует, впрочем, заметить, что часто встречается своеобразная
>   «симметрия» знаков (постановка запятой перед вторым тире, если перед
>   первым тире стоит запятая): Когда я стану умирать, — и, верь, тебе не
>   долго ждать, — ты перенесть меня вели в наш сад (Л.); Когда Косте,
>   сиротке-то, пошёл девятый годок, — а я в ту пору уже невестой была, —
>   повезла я его по всем гимназиям (Ч.); Когда всё кончилось, — а бой
>   длился около часу, — начдив сел на коня и шагом поехал по равнине (А.
>   Т.); Осенью, когда поспевали яблоки, — яблоневые деревья были
>   гордостью семейства Поповых, — Анатолий обычно спал на топчане в^саду,
>   чтобы мальчишки не покрали яблок (Ф.).
>
> ---

Розенталь - о деепричастном обороте вкупе со вставкой:

[...как перед первым, так и перед вторым тире ставится запятая по условиям текста:](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123)

> Проводя почти всё своё время неразлучно с матерью, потому что я и
>   писал и читал в её отдельной горнице, где обыкновенно и спал, — там
>   стояла моя кроватка и там был мой дом, — я менее играл с сестрицей,
>   реже виделся с ней (Акс.) — запятая перед первым тире закрывает
>   предшествующую придаточную часть, запятая перед вторым тире закрывает
>   деепричастную конструкцию;
>
> Я забрался в угол, в кожаное кресло, такое большое, что в нём можно
>   было лежать, — дедушка всегда хвастался, называя его креслом князя
>   Грузинского, — забрался и смотрел, как скучно веселятся большие (М.
>   Г.) — запятая перед первым тире закрывает предшествующую придаточную
>   часть, а запятая перед вторым тире закрывает деепричастный оборот в
>   самой вставной конструкции.

Comment: А деепричастный оборот здесь правильно употреблен?  Вроде бы он не соответствует  правилам Розенталя .http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm

Comment: Согласна, подозрительное предложение.

Comment: Какое подозрительно? Тут стока многа букафф... Я стока не могу прочесть, я по диагонали: по теме - не по теме. 8-(